# Java cast of ArrayList<Map>

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

sorry to say, I'm not very experienced with Java.
I'm using eclipse as IDE. 
Eclispe complains about unchecked cast which I can not understand.
Please refer to the code snipet. 
How to make this right in general ?

```
public Liberty2Server(ArrayList<Map<String,String>> libertySourceFiles , String basePath) throws FileNotFoundException , IllegalArgumentException {
    // check input file path
    for( Object map : libertySourceFiles) {
        Map<String,String> mp = (Map<String,String>) map ;  // <==Eclipse complains here: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,String>
```

Any hint is welcome

Rolf

Comment: A hint perhaps unrelated to your immediate issue. As soon as I start passing around complex collection compositions (e.g. a list of maps) I create a specific object representing and containing that. It makes the code less verbose and you can implement the population/iteration and pre/post-conditions in *one* place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse complains, because you want to cast an `Object` to a `Map<String, String>`. Change the type of your running variable `map` to `Map<String, String>`, and everything will be fine. You won't even need the variable `mp`then.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your for loop and use the explicit type in the collection:

```
for(Map<String,String> map : libertySourceFiles) {
    Map<String,String> mp = map; //probably not needed any more
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means you are performing a cast which the compiler cannot check is safe.

It warns you that you have to check it's safe.

A better solution is to remove the need for the cast by using

```
for(Map<String, String> mp : libertySourceFiles) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you upcast the `ArrayList<Map<String,String>>` element do `Object` and then downcast it to a generic type.
The solution is easy:

```
public Liberty2Server(ArrayList<Map<String,String>> libertySourceFiles , String basePath) throws FileNotFoundException , IllegalArgumentException {
    // check input file path
    for(  Map<String,String> mp : libertySourceFiles) {
      //  Map<String,String> mp = (Map<String,String>) map ; Not needed anymore
      ....
```